# Which is worth more - a chest of nickels or half a chest of dimes?

Tags: logical-deduction, lateral-thinking

I have two large identical chests of exactly the same shape, volume, etc. One is completely full of nickels (each worth 5 cents), and the other is exactly half full of dimes (each worth 10 cents). Which chest is worth more money?

Comment: If the chest is half full, I believe dimes are smaller than the 5c coins in the US right? So if the dime were equal size to the N (worst case) - same worth, so if you can pack 1 more dime in there.... So by volume: the half-chest of dimes surely? What do we know about packing?

Comment: Even if nickles and dimes were of equal weight and dimensions, and the monetary value in both chests was the same, I would rather drag home half a chest than a full chest.

Comment: It doesn't establish the last part of the necessary information - what is in the other half of the second chest?

Comment: @GlenO Stacks upon stacks of logic puzzles.

Comment: Packing is also important. You could fill two chests completely (meaning you can't add any more) with nickels and have wildly different numbers of coins in each chest, if you fill them in different ways.

Comment: If your chest was able to only hold one nickel, how many dimes could the chest hold?

Comment: Interesting to note, the dime and quarter (25 cent piece) have ratios of size/weight identical to their relative values. i.e. a jar full of quarters would be worth the same as a jar full of dimes, ignoring the packing issue which I suspect favors the dimes.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This required to get my wallet but it gave me the answer:

> The chest half full of dimes is worth more, this because a dime is smaller than a nickle, so it would occupy less space and there would be more dimes in a full chest than there would be in a full chest of nickels. Conclusion: pick the dimes, It's worth more

Comment: The chest of dimes would be worth at least twice as much since dimes are both smaller in diameter and about half the thickness. More math would need to be done to verify exactly how much difference there will be.

Answer (score 53):

Here's another way to see it:

> The chests themselves are worth exactly the same, as they are identical. The contents, on the other hand, might differ.

*EDIT*: As some people have pointed out, this is an even larger stretch than before if one considers the title as well as the question itself. I didn't.

Comment: It doesn't get any more lateral than this! +1

Comment: @dmg lateral by way of literal

Comment: That's cute, and got a smile from me, but it's a stretch.  In regular language it is clearly understood that the value of a container includes its contents, unless otherwise stated.   (Is 50 cents a good price for a bag of chips?  Only if it includes buying the chips inside it :)

Comment: The title is confusing.  The chest itself would be worth less if it were `half a chest` like the title says, but this answer is good with regard to the question (not the title).

Comment: It also says the chests are identical.  If half a chest is identical to a whole chest, it must be a degenerate zero-volume chest, so neither one has any contents to consider.

Comment: In my experience, a Ball pint jar and a Ball quart jar can each be had, with ring and lid, empty, a la carte, both new and second hand, for the same price in a number of retail contexts (noted, when sold as in a case, a differential price usually emerges).

Comment: Yeah, it's a stretch. And a large one if one regards the title of the question :)

Comment: I'd argue that "half a chest" is worth really very little compared to a whole, not-broken-in-half chest. So depending on the value of the chest...

Answer (score 24):

It's not that easy!

Dimes have a *nominal value* of 10 cents, whereas the *material value* is only about 5.6 cents. Which means the *nominal* value is decisive.

Nickels have a *nominal value* of 5 cents but a *material value* of 10.09 cents (source: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nickel_%28United_States_coin%29#Increase_in_metal_values)). Which means that the *material value* is decisive (makes you wonder why people aren't buying large amounts of nickels and reselling the metal...).

Further, dimes are not only smaller in diameter than nickels but also slimmer (17.9mm versus 21.2mm diameter and 1.35 versus 1.95mm). That means that the same volume can hold a larger number of dimes than it could hold nickels. It is not possible to tell exactly how many more nickels will fit into the same volume (or into half that volume, for that matter) since this greatly depends not only on stacking, but also on implementation details of the surrounding box. If the box is just half a millimeter too small to exactly fit a complete row of coins, you're drifting far away from the optimal packing, for example.

However, in order to answer the question, it is not necessary at all to know the exact number of coins that will fit. Since both coins are (almost exactly) worth the same, you must have the same number of coins in either case. That is, you must be able to fit *the same number* of dimes into half the volume, or twice the number of dimes into the same volume. This is certainly not the case, you can only fit roughly 1/3 more dimes into the same volume, give or take a few.

Thus, the box of nickels is more valuable.

Comment: I believe that the OP mentioned in the question that nickels are worth five cents and dimes are worth ten cents. However, your answer is pretty interesting if you ignore the conditions stated in the question.

Comment: @mmking: Well, there's the tag "lateral thinking", so I thought melting the nickles and selling the metal (disregarding nominal value) would be a valid approach  :-)

Comment: `makes you wonder why people aren't buying large amounts of nickels and resell the metal...` because it is illegal i think.

Comment: _Section 331 of Title 18 of the United States code provides criminal penalties for anyone who fraudulently alters, defaces, mutilates impairs, diminishes, falsifies, scales, or lightens any of the coins coined at the Mints of the United States. This statute means that you may be violating the law if you change the appearance of the coin and fraudulently represent it to be other than the altered coin that it is. As a matter of policy, the Mint does not promote coloring, plating or altering U.S. coinage: however, there are no sanctions against such activity absent fraudulent intent._

Comment: The above being said, it is illegal to deface a coin or currency to pass it off as something that it isn't. However, there is no law which specifically makes it illegal to melt down US coins. It is a bit of a legal gray area.

Comment: @JasonHutchinson It's not a "legal gray area" by far -- melting down U.S. cents and nickels is punishable by $10k fine and up to 5 years in jail. http://www.usmint.gov/pressroom/?action=press_release&ID=771

Comment: @JasonHutchinson I don't think it's quite that simple. Just because it's a "rule" does that mean they'll necessarily win in court? I'd say the fact that you  _own_ a coin pretty much gives you the right to do what you want to it. The crime is trying to commit a fraud - which you're not. Besides, the maximum fine is only $10k so you'd easily be able to pay that out of your illgotten profits!

Comment: Sorry Jason Hutchinson, the above was aimed at @Atsby.

Comment: @Lefty Lots of nutters think you don't have to follow IRS "rules" either. Guess where some of them end up?

Comment: "Protects taxpayers from bearing the costs to replace coins withdrawn from circulation?"  Why do they need to be replaced?   Isn't it time for pennies and nickels to be retired anyway?  What a waste of time.

Comment: @Atsby that's the way the U.S. law is, sure - but there isn't anything preventing you from melting them elsewhere, i.e. China - and as far as exporting large amounts of the coins, you would have to declare the $$ amount and possibly pay taxes on it, but it's not exactly illegal either.

Comment: @user2813274 yes there is. "the United States Mint introduced new interim rules on December 14, 2006, that criminalized the melting and *export* of pennies (which as of 2013 cost 1.83 cents to produce) and nickels."

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nickel_%28United_States_coin%29#Increase_in_metal_values

Comment: @Damon - I don't know where you got your numbers from, but you can pack roughly twice as many dimes in a space as you can nickels (assuming the space is large compared to the coins. Your answer is incorrect.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast - yes, but you have only half the volume for the nickels... this answer assumes the intrinsic rather than nominal value of the coins drives the answer (as the comment thread shows, that assumption is only valid if you are willing to break the law...). Incidentally, according to http://www.coinflation.com/ , the intrinsic (metal melt) value of neither coin exceeds its face value: it lists the nickel at 3.8 cents, and the dime at 1.5 cent. Only copper pennies are worth more melted down. Note the cost of MAKING the coins is greater - but that is irrelevant.

Comment: According to wikipedia, the cost of MAKING the nickel exceeds the face value; but that is **not** the MELT value.

Answer (score 17):

> [Nickel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nickel_%28United_States_coin%29)
>   value per volume:
>
> $$\frac{5 ¢}{\pi(\frac{21.21}{2}\ \text{mm})^2 * 1.95\ \text{mm}} = \frac{7.257 ¢}{\text{mL}}$$
>
> [Dime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dime_%28United_States_coin%29):
>
> $$\frac{10 ¢}{\pi(\frac{17.91}{2}\ \text{mm})^2 * 1.35\ \text{mm}} = \frac{29.40 ¢}{\text{mL}}$$
>
> So, for large volumes with reasonable dimensions$\dagger$, if you had
>   twice the volume of nickels as dimes, the nickels would worth about
>   half as much as the dimes.
>
> $\dagger$ I say *reasonable dimensions* because fringe effects come
>   into play if you have to pay attention to the coins bumping into the
>   wall.

Comment: You haven't taken into account packing density in your calculation. It will have the same net effect on both values, assuming an arbitrarily large volume compared to the objects being packed, scaling by a ratio of ~0.9069. (Exact value: pi/(2*root(3)))

Comment: Also, I think you meant the dime equation to be $10¢/V$, not $5¢/V$. :-)

Comment: @AndrewCoonce, as you say, packing density affects both values by the same fraction, so doesn't change which is more valuable.

Answer (score -2):

It is heavily dependent on the rarity and collectibility of the coins involved. As we are talking about *worth*, not *value*, it is subject to much more than just the dollar amount put on the two types of coins. As the problem statement gives no real indicators of *worth*, I'm going to call BS and say that there ins't enough information.

Comment: The OP very clearly states the worth of each coin.